# Getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to encode XXX as a byte stream."

Tags: java, rest-assured

I want to extract JSON data from a string. Here is my code:

```
String APIBody = "{\"queryString\": \"Pearson AND unscrubbed:false\"}";
RequestSpecBuilder rbuild = new RequestSpecBuilder();
rbuild.setBody(APIBody);
rbuild.setContentType("application json;charset = UTF-8");
RequestSpecification rSpec = rbuild.build();
Response resp = given().headers(headers).spec(rSpec).when().post("https://content-service.stg-prsn.com/csg/api/v2/search");
```

In the final line, I am passing multiple headers as a hashmap.

I get the following error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to encode {"queryString": "Pearson AND unscrubbed:false"} as a byte stream.
>
> Please use EncoderConfig (EncoderConfig#encodeContentTypeAs) to specify how to serialize data for this content-type.
> For example: "given().config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("application json", ContentType.TEXT))). .."
>   at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.EncoderRegistry.encodeStream(EncoderRegistry.java:129)
> ```

Comment: Not sure that's the reason, but try change to  `rbuild.setContentType("application/json;charset = UTF-8");`

Comment: Indented code correctly,

Answer (score 2):

I seems that RestAssured is not clever enough to understand the content type JSON with the charset. The easy solution is to replace

```
setContentType("application json;charset = UTF-8");
```

With the enum *io.restassured.http.ContentType*:

```
setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `javajson.jar` instead of `restassured`. I tried using `restassured` api given below:

```
Response resp = given().config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(((Object) encoderConfig()).encodeContentTypeAs("application json", APIBody)));
```

but the following methods were missing/not defined in the jar file
config:

> The method config() is undefined for the type RestAssured
>   encodeContentTypeAs
>
> The method encodeContentTypeAs(String, String) is undefined for the
>   type Object

Answer (score 0):

try to give in the below way

```
Response res = given()
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .body(APIBody)
                .with()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .then()
                .post(url);
```

Thanks